# Ayuda en estructura de una clase en java

Tags: java

Estoy iniciando en java y quisiera saber si estoy realizando bien esta clase en java, me gustaria saber si los commentarios que le e puesto a cada linea son correctos, y tambien me gustaria saber que es lo que hace la linea 13 **obj.estudiante();**

Si pueden ayudarme a comentar mas lineas seria ideal, asi me queda mucho mas clara toda la estructura de esta clase.

```
 public class Estudiante // creamos la clase estudiante
{
    public void edadEstudiante() // Este es el método
    {   //variable local edad
        int edad = 0; // Declaramos la variable age que vale 0 y es de tipo int
        edad = edad + 5;
        System.out.println("La edad del estudiante es : " + edad);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) // método main
    {
        Estudiante obj = new Estudiante(); // se crea el objeto de la clase
        obj.edadEstudiante();
    }
}
```

Comment: lo que hace la linea 13 es llamar al metodo estudiante que definiste arriba

Comment: Muchas gracias, el resto de los comentarios que puse estan bien?

Comment: un dato, se tiene por costumbre llamar al constructor igual que la clase, ahora por que te dije que era un metodo por que tiene la palabra clave void en la cabecera

Comment: Y otra cosa: los nombres de clase por convencion comienzan con mayuscula

Comment: Muchas gracias, tengo dudas con la linea 12, esta bien lo que puse?

Comment: Ahi lo edite, me refiero al comentario que puse esta bien planteado?

Comment: si esta bien ahi

Comment: lo ultimo en los metodos la primera letra va con minuscula, asi puedes diferenciarlos de las clases

Answer (score 1):

Bueno aquí van mis observaciones.
Los comentarios de métodos están mal ubicados, van antes de la declaración del método y se declaran con 2 asteriscos `/** ....*/` ya que es la descripción del método

Los comentarios de línea si es a tu juicio y por lo general se trata de comentar en inglés pero si no tienes conocimiento bueno, en Español, mejor comentar en Español que no hacerlo.

Supongo que el método que declaras `public void estudiante()` tenga la intención de ser el constructor porque declaras una edad para dicho estudiante, de ser así no se pone el `void`.

Los nombres de las clases son con Mayúsculas y el constructor al igual que la clase con mayúsculas.

Los métodos se nombran por convenio en notación Camel que es la primera letra minúscula y si hay otra palabra se alterna la mayúsculas 
Ej: `private void imprimirEdad ()`

Si la variable edad quieres que sea un atributo de la clase has de declararla como tal, no dentro método sino fuera, antes del constructor escribiendo algo así 
`private int edad;`

De esta forma puedes crear las funciones get (obtiene el valor de la edad) y set (asigna un valor a la edad) para dicho atributo.

```
public int getEdad(){
   return this.edad;
}
public void setEdad(int edad){
   this.edad = edad;
}
```

Espero que se entienda lo mejor posible.

EDIT: aquí dejo un link con más detalle
https://javadesdecero.es/fundamentos/convenciones-nomenclatura-java/